# How to install a third party apk using Android Studio so that the tests, I have created, can run on the third party apk?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, junit

While I create a new project, I change the package name to that of the third party apk package name (*com.apowersoft.mirror*) and select the Empty script and save.

I create a new (small) test script within the package then connect my android device and run the test.

The error message below is displayed:

```
//Testing started at 11:01 ...
// 10/24 11:01:50: Launching ExampleTest...
//$ adb push C:\Users\LOCAL.ADMIN\Android Studio Test 
//Files\Practice\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
```

> The app-debug apk is the apk that is automatically built upon running the script (I do not need this apk so I deleted it and tried to replace it with the third party apk (ApowerMirror app) but that did not work. The apk just appeared in the folder again after I re-ran the script.)

```
///data/local/tmp/com.apowersoft.mirror
//$ adb shell pm install -t -r 
//"/data/local/tmp/com.apowersoft.mirror"
//pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.apowersoft.mirror
//Success


//$ adb push C:\Users\LOCAL.ADMIN\Android Studio Test 
//Files\Practice\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\debug\app-debug- 
//androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/com.apowersoft.mirror
//$ adb shell pm install -t -r 
//"/data/local/tmp/com.apowersoft.mirror.test"
//pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.apowersoft.mirror.test
//Success


//Running tests

//$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class
//'com.apowersoft.mirror.ExampleTest'
//com.apowersoft.mirror.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
//Client not ready yet..
//Started running tests
```

> Immediately after this, my first test fails. see below (in bold)

//**android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObjectNotFoundException: 
     UiSelector[TEXT=Register]**

In which folder should I put the third party apk file (ApowerMirror app) that I want to test?

**Please note:** When I have the apk already installed on my device and I run the test script, I receive the error message below (Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]) and when I uninstall it and try again, the error message above is displayed:

```
//Testing started at 12:47 ...

//10/25 12:47:29: Launching ExampleTest
//$ adb push C:\Users\LOCAL.ADMIN\Android Studio Test 
//Files\MyApplication\myapp\build\outputs\apk\debug\myapp-debug.apk 
///data/local/tmp/com.smartvg.tcr.aevi
//$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.smartvg.tcr.aevi"
//pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.smartvg.tcr.aevi
//Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```